# comment system in Yii

Tags: yii

I tried to create comments in Yii 1.1 from this example http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/en/comment.create but I have 404 error on the post page(where should render content and comment form on the bottom of the page). I think I have error in the actionView in the PostController as in the example code is

```
 $post=$this->loadModel();
    $comment=$this->newComment($post);

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$post,
        'comment'=>$comment,
    ));
```

and in my controller intial code is `$this->render('view',array('model'=>$this->loadModel($id),`

I created comment model in the gii and created comment in crud.

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
            $post=$this->loadModel();
            $comment=$this->newComment($post);

            $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$post,
            'comment'=>$comment,
            //$this->loadModel($id),                

        ));
    }

protected function newComment($post)
{
    $comment=new Comment;
    if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
    {
        $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
        if($post->addComment($comment))
        {
            if($comment->status==Comment::STATUS_PENDING)
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted','Thank you for your comment. Your comment will be posted once it is approved.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    return $comment;
}
```

In the Post model:

```
public function addComment($comment)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->params['commentNeedApproval'])
            $comment->status=Comment::STATUS_PENDING;
        else
            $comment->status=Comment::STATUS_APPROVED;
        $comment->post_id=$this->id;
        return $comment->save();
    }
```

In the protected/views/post/view.php

```
<div id="comments">
    <?php if($model->commentCount>=1): ?>
        <h3>
            <?php echo $model->commentCount . 'comment(s)'; ?>
        </h3>

        <?php $this->renderPartial('_comments',array(
            'post'=>$model,
            'comments'=>$model->comments,
        )); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In the last line of your question, did you mean yii?

Comment: show teh code/url for calling the acction .. then show also all tha action Code (declaration of action function too)

Comment: added the code.

Comment: I dont't see how you call the action .. but anyway are you sure you have a view.php file in the views/comment directory?

Comment: I don't have such folder and view as in the example they didn't mention that there should be such view

Comment: I added the comment form here /protected/views/post/view.php

Answer (score 0):

In your actionView method, you are not passing through $id to loadModel(). It should be something like this.

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
            $post=$this->loadModel($id);
            $comment=$this->newComment($post);

            $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$post,
            'comment'=>$comment,
            //$this->loadModel($id),                

        ));
    }
```

Otherwise, the loadModel method will throw a 404 error since it can't find anything to load.